# Windows Phone 8 and REST

Tags: wcf, rest, windows-phone-8

I need to use REST web services under Windows Phone 8, but there is no System.ServiceModel.Web  namespace in WP framework so I cannot use WebGet and WebInvoke annotations.

How am I supposed to do HTTP GET calls using WCF? Is WCF supported in Windows Phone 8?

**EDIT**

The only approach that I can think off now is to use direct approach using HttpWebRequest and handle everything by hand. I wanted to avoid this since this approach brings too much boilerplate code inside the production code. This is why WCF is here. I can't even use RealProxy to implement some basic facilities myself since it's not supported either. The only solution that brings some automation and removes boilerplate code is to use dynamic and DLR features with DynamicObject, that will resolve the calls in runtime, but this will strip me of from static compiler checking.

Why did Microsoft remove crucial parts of framework from WP8? I don't get it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why did Microsoft remove crucial parts of framework from WP8?

They were never present. Such APIs would be considered features. And with frameworks like [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) there's little need to trouble yourself with writing anything by hand.

Comment: Thank you. I was using WCF in Silverlight and thought it's on the WP platform. Bat back to RestSharp. I tried to install it via NuGet but it failed because it's not compatible with WP8 platform. Is there any such a framework that's usable on WP8? And is there any framework that supports proxy interface like WCF or SpringMVC?

Comment: It's compatible if you use the source code from GitHub, rather than the NuGet package. The NuGet package just haven't been updated yet.